# OpenTelemetry: Traces Split Between Zipkin Replicas in Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, zipkin

I'm using **OpenTelemetry** in my **scala** project for **tracing** and seeing traces in **zipkin**.

I'm creating tracer object as:

```
object OpenTelemetry {

  val urlForZipkin ="http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans"

  private val exporter: ZipkinSpanExporter = ZipkinSpanExporter.builder()
    .setEndpoint(applicationConfig.getString("urlForZipkin"))
    .build()

  private val labelSet: Attributes = Attributes.builder().put("service.name", "my-service").build()

  private val tracerProvider: SdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder()
    .addSpanProcessor(SimpleSpanProcessor.create(exporter))
    .setResource(Resource.create(labelSet))
    .build()

  private val openTelemetry: OpenTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
    .setTracerProvider(tracerProvider)
    .build()

  val tracer: Tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer("myTracer")
}
```

I'm using this tracer object for creating `spans` and `childSpans` in `controller`, `services` and `actors` (`all over the project`), here is the code for creating span and childSpan :

```
val span = tracer.spanBuilder("my-route: Span").startSpan()

val childSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("child-span")
      .setParent(Context.current.`with`(span))
      .startSpan()
```

I'm running this project on **k8's pod** having **two replicas** of zipkin  **deployment**.
The issue with this is that, it is `sending half traces` to one zipkin replica and another `half is sending to other zipkin` replica.
I've checked, the `tracer ID` of all span and childSpan is `same`.

However if I set the `zipkin replica to one` it is working fine and all the traces are going to that zipkin replica.

Here is my `deployment` of zipkin:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zipkin-deployment
  namespace: my-ns

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zipkin-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: zipkin-pod
      labels:
        app: zipkin-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zipkin
          image: openzipkin/zipkin
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9411

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zipkin
  namespace: my-ns

spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: zipkin-label
  ports:
    - port: 9411
      targetPort: 9411
```

I want to send all the traces of one request to one zipkin pod, How can I achieve this ?